# Point wise convergent of bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis

If ($f_n$) is sequence of bounded functions on R which converges pointwise to $f$ then can f is also bounded????  If not,then is it true when there is uniform convergence??

Comment: $f_n(x) = x \chi_{[0,n]}$

Comment: @RRL Please expain a little bit

Comment: For your first question this is a sequence of bounded functions that converges pointwise to $f(x) = x$ for $x \geqslant 0$ -- hence, unbounded.

Comment: Try to show some work or the question will inevitably be closed.  Try to complete my arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 2 Hint: Show uniform convergence implies uniform boundedness.

We have $|f_n(x)| \leqslant M_n$ for all $n$. There exists $N$ such that $|f(x) - f_n(x)| < 1$ for all $n \geqslant N$ and all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and

$$|f_n(x)| \leqslant |f_n(x) - f(x)| + |f(x) - f_N(x)| + |f_N(x)|$$